# Is there any way to get the Multi-Safari version of Safari 2 working on Snow Leopard?

Tags: snow-leopard, safari

Michel Fortin’s [Multi-Safari](http://michelf.com/projects/multi-safari/) actually makes it possible to test websites in old versions of Safari, should you feel the need.

Unfortunately, the Multi-Safari version of Safari 2 doesn’t quite work properly in Snow Leopard. For me, it worked for a few minutes. Then, for no apparent reason, it stopped loading web pages — the progress bar would stay stuck at a fairly short length, and the status bar would say it was waiting for the web site.

Is there any way to get it working reliably on Snow Leopard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari 2, sorry, why would you need to test for that? It's REALLY not in use by anyone anymore.

Anyway, the best way I can think of running it is to virtualise an earlier version of OS X - Tiger or Jaguar.

Comment: “It's REALLY not in use by anyone anymore.” — A statement which holds perfectly until someone, somewhere, complains that your site doesn’t work on Safari 2. I do entirely take your point though.

Comment: Oh — [is it possible to virtualize PowerPC versions of Mac OS X on an Intel Mac](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22262/can-you-virtualize-powerpc-versions-of-mac-os-x-on-intel-macs)?

Comment: You can virtualise OS X 10.4.4-10.4.8 (Intel) with some effort - there were some hackintosh techniques for doing it. I'll try find some.
Ask you can see here the Safari 3 install base is really minuscule, Safari 2 will be even tinier.